# Email Edited HTML Output of an Oracle SQL Query

Tags: php, html, sql, oracle

Thank you for anyone who can help me with this!
What i have is an oracle database and i display all open work tickets using while and oci_fetch_row (page pickupready.php).
Each row is displayed in the table and has a checkbox to click on. User clicks multiple checkboxes selecting the rows (work tickets) they need and click Submit button.
New page (sendpickup.php) opens only showing table with rows that were selected by user. Then user has an ability to type quantity for each of the rows and then they click Send Pickup button which should email this output with their entered quantities and pickup times.
My question is how to grab everything that was output on that page + user edited information and email it using php mail() function?
This is my sendpickup.php page:

```
echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
echo "<table class = 'pickup'>\n";
echo "<tr style='background-color: orange'>\n";
echo "<th>CXL Date</th><th>Customer</th>";
echo "<th>WO #</th><th>Lot #</th><th>Style</th><th>Color</th><th>Original Qty</th>";
echo "<th>Cut Qty</th><th>Cut Date</th><th>Pickup Qty</th><th>Pickup Time</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr style='background-color: #FFFFFF'>\n";
echo "<td>".($row[1] !== null ? htmlentities($row[1], ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
echo "<td>".($row[2] !== null ? htmlentities($row[2], ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
echo "<td>".($row[3] !== null ? htmlentities($row[3], ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
echo "<td>".($row[4] !== null ? htmlentities($row[4], ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
echo "<td>".($row[5] !== null ? htmlentities($row[5], ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
echo "<td>".($row[6] !== null ? htmlentities($row[6], ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
echo "<td>".($row[7] !== null ? htmlentities($row[7], ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
echo "<td>".($row[8] !== null ? htmlentities($row[8], ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
echo "<td>".($row[9] !== null ? htmlentities($row[9], ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
echo "<td><input size= '5' style = 'color: red; font-weight: bold' value = $row[8]></td>";
echo "<td><input size= '5' style = 'color: red; font-weight: bold' value = '9 AM'></td>";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name = 'sendpickup' value='Send Pickup'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Then i use following to send an email:

```
if (isset($_POST['sendpickup'])) 
{
$to  = 'wip@abc.com';
$subject = 'READY FOR PICKUP';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: WIP <wip@abc.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ABC User<wip@abc.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header( 'Location: pickupready.php');
}
```

Basically my page sendpickup.php works correctly, mail() function works too and my only problem is how to grab data for my $message variable.

i can use grab everything from sql output and assign to this variable but i cannot figure out how to send user information filled out in these 2 input boxes:

```
echo "<td><input size= '5' style = 'color: red; font-weight: bold' value = $row[8]></td>";
echo "<td><input size= '5' style = 'color: red; font-weight: bold' value = '9 AM'></td>";
```

so as of right now i do something very basic. I select my output table by dragging mouse over it, then use a copy paste into email and email it manually. It works for time being but i really want to automate this and yet can't figure out how. I apologize if this was asked before - i tried to search but couldn't find any information and i cannot figure it out myself.
thank you again!

Comment: Give your inputs a `name` attribute, similar to what you did for the submit button, then retrieve the values using `$_POST` similar to what you did with the submit button, and then set `$message` to the value of the posted inputs?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Problem is that i am using ob_start() and ob_get_contents() to capture the output of the query but this doesn't capture any user changes. How would i be able to capture all of my output with user changes if i don't use ob_start()?